# I can not get dropdownlist value in mvc3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

i have a form by dropdownlist element. i want get value of dropdownlist in controller.
i do not know how can do this. i read my username of users with dataview in controller and want to change role of them by dropdownlist options.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<form name="register" action="#"> 
<div>

  <table>

      @foreach (MembershipUser user in Model)
        {
            var userroles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      @user.UserName
                  </td>
                  @foreach (var role in userroles)
                     {
                          <td>
                              @role
                          </td>
                    }

                  <td>
                       @Html.DropDownList("roleName")
                       @Html.ValidationMessage("roleName")

                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
      }       

  </table>
<input type="submit" class="register" value="Save" />
</div>

    </form>

   }
```

and this is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["roleName"] = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName");
        return View(Membership.GetAllUsers()); 
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
public ActionResult Index(string roleNameSelectedValue)
{
    // roleNameSelectedValue is the "Value" field of selected item in your dropdownlist
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Or using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.roleName, ViewBag.roleName as SelectList)`

Comment: i tried this and get error in write value on page with response.write(roleNameSelectValue)